# .Net Core 3.0 SignalR client connection problem

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr.client

I created 2 project. First project is .net core mvc application works with SignalR and the second one is client. So in my server is running however when I want to connect from console.app to signalR I got some error.

Here is an codes. (Client)

```
HubConnection conn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl("http://localhost:5001/userHub")
             .Build();

        conn.StartAsync().ContinueWith(t=>{
            if(t.IsFaulted)
                Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.GetBaseException());
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Hub");

        }).Wait();
```

Server:

```
  public class UserHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"New Connection {Context.ConnectionId}");

        Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage","New Connection Id", Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

Server (Configuration)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<UserHub>("/userHub");
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIg3U.png)

Comment: Hi @user3304820, any updates about this issue? Did you try to modify the URL as I mentioned in post?

Answer (score 4):

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.

I can reproduce same issue with the URL `http://localhost:5001/userHub` while it is serving at `https://localhost:5001` and `http://localhost:5000` by runing **dotnet run** command.

To fix the issue, please modify the code to `.WithUrl("https://localhost:5001/userHub")`.

*SignalR .NET client*

```
Console.WriteLine("Signalr Client Starting...");

HubConnection conn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:5001/userHub")
    .Build();

conn.StartAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
    if (t.IsFaulted)
        Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.GetBaseException());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Hub");

}).Wait();
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: This sorted it for me. I was just using http like I would for my local API calls and it wasn't working, changing it to https seemed to allow the connection to take place.